# Javascript cycle of execution

Tags: javascript, synchronous

I've one script who is including another by this way :

```
 <script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8">
        //<![CDATA[
        ; (function (window, document, ud) {
            var AnId = 654654;
            var script                = document.createElement('script');
            script.setAttribute('charset', 'UTF-8');       
            script.setAttribute('src', '//something.com/blabla.js');
            script.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
            document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
        })(window, document);
    //]]>

       var AnId = 65777;
     </script>
```

My blabla.js must be executed right after being included to have the correct AnId value(654654) how can I deal with this execution order.
Or is there another approach.

My final goal is to include several time the same script(with different id) without collision between them.

Comment: I can solve this problem with url rewriting, passing the id to an dynamic script through the url

Comment: I don't see anything asynchronous in that or am I missing something?

Comment: @Liam, is loading a script in this way done synchronously? Do you have to add the `async` attribute?

Comment: @Liam synchronous or asynchronous depend of in witch point of view you are (problem or solution)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
script.async = false;
```

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script:

> Set this Boolean attribute to indicate that the browser should, if
>   possible, execute the script asynchronously. It has no effect on
>   inline scripts (i.e., scripts that don't have the src attribute).

Answer (score 1):

You can use onload event handler to create and run the second script:

```
script.onload = function() {
  runTheSecondScript();
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the "load" event to make sure you will execute the following code in the proper time.

```
script.addEventListener('load', function(){
  var AnId = 65777;
});
```